# Add disk partition for Ubuntu Virtualbox Virtual Machine

Tags: partitioning, virtualbox

I have a Virtualbox Virtual Machine running Ubuntu 20.04 with 32 GB disk space. When trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 I get the message: to less disk space. So within Virtualbox Manager I could increase the size of the VM to 64 GB.

But still I could not upgrade, because Ubuntu does not recognize this free space. Within the VM I run ¨Disk" and indeed I see Volume of 69 GB (I thought this should be 64 GB, but it is not important). And I can see there is a ¨Free space"of 34 GB.

So I would like to use this free space. F.e. as a new partition. In the help documentation of "Disk" I could not find any information, nor in the official Ubuntu documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-help/index.html .It should be quite easy. But I am very careful, a mistake is easily made and will have a huge consequence.

How can I make the free space can be used by Ubuntu. Preferably within the ¨Disk" software.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps are needed.

1. I hover over the ´+'button and saw ¨Create partition in unallocated space¨. I did so, and indeed the space was added.
2. When running the upgrade, still there was not enough space on ´/' So I had to move some data from ´/' to the new partition. Now the upgrade was possible, so the added space seems to be accessible by Ubuntu.

It is a pity so much research work is needed, for a simple upgrade of Ubuntu within Virtualbox.